# Can I show files on Windows desktop which are in a different folder on disk

Tags: windows-7, desktop, shared-folders

I have a shared folder on my network called PUBLIC.  I like to see all of my files on the desktop instead of using explorer to view them.  The problem is, all of my files need to be inside the PUBLIC share so that other people on the network can use them!  Is there a way for me to tell Windows to show the files/folders from PUBLIC as the contents of my desktop?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you want to view your public files e.g. public folder, on your desktop. Or if you want to to make files on your desktop viewable to the public. I suppose you could make a shortcut on your desktop to your public folder. Or you could make a folder on your desktop public. But I am not sure whether you can do individual files.

Comment: I want to make the files in the public folder show up on my desktop "as if" they were actually on my desktop.

Comment: what if you go to your desktop, then right click..new...shortcut  then point to the shared file?

Comment: @barlop I would have to do that for every file in the folder.... there's hundreds of them.

Comment: how about doing a shortcut to the folder?  If you don't want to have to double click into a folder.. Another option is to look into how toautomatically generate shortcuts. It is probably possible to create shortcuts with a script or in a programming language. You may want to ask on SO re Visual Studio, but here somebody answers it re powershell http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701840/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-powershell

Comment: Here's your answer: http://superuser.com/questions/328763/can-you-change-the-location-of-the-desktop-folder-in-windows

Answer (score 1):

"Fences" does that. Among its features, it creates "folder portals" in the desktop.

http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/download.asp