# Sharing the same desktop between different users

Tags: windows-7, windows, active-directory, domain, shared-folders

We have a domain/AD setup, no roaming folders. Most computers are used by one person, some are shared by different people with different responsibilities, and some are shared by different people with the same responsibilities.

My question is regarding the last type. I know I can create a folder under `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`, make it writeable for all users, and they can share stuff in it, but it would be much simpler and less error-prone if I can somehow set these particular computers such as the Desktop folder/library of any user who logs in on them point to the same folder.

The users can maintain personal Documents/AppData/Music etc... But their desktop folder is the same as for everyone else using this computer.

Is such thing doable?

Comment: Why the desktop? Why not just create a normal folder e.g. `C:\Share` and place a shortcut for it on the user desktop?

Comment: @Seth Because that's where almost all average users store stuff, right on the desktop. Like I said, a folder on the public desktop is a solution, and everyone can see it, but you can't really count on everyone actually using it, either they forget to, or they just find it an additional hassle for them.

Comment: You might try using [folder redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275(v=ws.11).aspx) or `mklink` but educating your users is probably the better option. see also the following question as it might have an answer: [Can you change the location of the Desktop folder in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/328763/can-you-change-the-location-of-the-desktop-folder-in-windows)

Comment: I definitely agree with Seth's assessment.  We are always glad to help, but this is more of an end-user education challenge than a technical problem.  Taking it a step further, you don't have a file server on the domain?  In my experience, end-users are only too happy to fill up a file server with shared files and folders.

Comment: We do actually, we have personal folders and department folders, and that's another challenge we have, getting them to actually use them, instead of requesting file moving everytime we buy new laptops/desktops.

Comment: If that's the case, I would try to emphasize the file server.  On our domain, we use Group Policy Preferences to automatically map the file server shares for each end user:  the "P:" drive is for their personal files, the "W:" drive is for the teams' working files, etc.  It sounds like you have a nice tech solution available for your end-users, but their mental perspective is still focused as though they were working on a computer at home.  Again, some customer education seems like it could alleviate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location of each user's desktop by right clicking on desktop under This PC and then properties. Under the location tab you can see the location of the desktop files and change it