# Is there any way to change what folder is shown on your desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop

I am wondering if there is a way to change which file is shown on your desktop, I do a lot of stuff from the command line so i like my files to be close to the home directory, but i also like to have access to the files from the desktop. is there any way to do this or do i need to use a load of shortcuts for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/328763/can-you-change-the-location-of-the-desktop-folder-in-windows

Comment: It's not the exact solution i had in mind, but this would be find since i would only need to navigate into one folder, thanks for the help.

Comment: Or how about starting your command line directly with the desktop by using "cmd /k cd desktop" as shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

You must hide the file and then don't show the hidden files. To do that:

- Right-click the file you want to hide. Go to properties.

[image]

- Check the box that says `Hide file`

[image]

[image]

- Open the file explorer
- Go to the '*view*' panel
- Click the '*options*' button at the upper-right side of the explorer

[image]

- Go to view again and then mark the '*don't show*' option at the '*show hidden files and folders*'

[image]

- Repeat with all files and folders

Now your files don't use space at the desktop but they are there. In case you can't access an specified file, use the commands with administrator permissions.

Good luck!