# Get path of the Desktop folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file

I have a batch script that need the full path of the Desktop folder.

Right now I am using `%USERPROFILE%/Desktop`, it works fine until I learned that the path can be changed (See [Can you change the location of the Desktop folder in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/328763/can-you-change-the-location-of-the-desktop-folder-in-windows)).

I tried to read the regedit and I end up with something like this (I have cygwin installed):

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Current
Version\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v Desktop |grep Desktop| awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'
```

This is working fine but I don't like it for the sake of robust and simplicity. Not to metion that it will be even more messy if I don't have `awk` avaliable.

As I noticed, you can type `shell:Desktop` in File Explorer and it will open the Desktop folder for you. However I have no clue how I can use that in a batch file.

Is there a hidden environment variable or simple command I can use to retrive this value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no environment variables for the majority of special folders. The official method is to call either [SHGetKnownFolderPath()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) from Win32 API or [System.Environment.GetFolderPath()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-5.0) from .NET – the latter is easily [accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747246/49849) through PowerShell:

```
$dir = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
```

Batch scripts (Cmd.exe) do not have access to such features; you would have to call a program that does (such as PowerShell or third-party tools like [nircmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)).

Comment: This is the way to go: it "survives" the poor implementation of OneDrive's backup functionality. (If you decide to backup your Desktop with OneDrive, it **moves** the folder from its original location to a magically maintained folder of its choosing.)